# Different output for native and SpringData Query

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a user collection with documents having org array with multiples values. The problem here is that the Spring API returns 3 documents. But the Org data is null instead of individual array data. The native query is working perfectly returning org data with values.

I am using Spring Data version 1.10.1.RELEASE

Following is my native query

```
   db.users.aggregate([ 
     { $unwind: "$Org" }
   ])
```

The above query returns 3 documents because org array contains 3  data.

Following is my equivalent SpringData API

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
             unwind("Org"),
    );
    AggregationResults<UserDTO> groupResults = 
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Users.class, Users.class);
    return  groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: How does your `UserDTO` looks like ? You can do `groupResults.getRawResults()` to see the data from mongodb before it is mapped to DTO

Comment: how is that you have specified that your input and output class both as `Users.class` and you are assigning the return value to `UserDTO`

Comment: I can able to view org array values in the raw result. But not in the getMappedResult. My UserDTO looks like the following  
 
@Document(collection = "users")
public class UserDTO {

 @Id
 private String userId;
 private String login;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String createdOn;
 private String email;
 private boolean deactivateFlag;
 private HashSet<UserOrgMapDTO> userOrgMap;
 private String createdBy;

Comment: UserDTO is a mistake which I have corrected before getting this error. Is it a mistake to have input and output same as users.class ? I only query a single collection in my query.

Comment: Does anyone have a working example of aggregation with unwind which gives documents with individual array values in the getMappedResult() ?